# How to use switchable Radeon HD graphics for Flatpak apps?

Tags: kubuntu, radeon, amd-graphics, flatpak, switchable-graphics

How to use switchable Radeon HD graphics for Flatpak apps? 
HP Pavilion G6
Dual booting with Windows 7
OS: Kubuntu 18.04 64bit
Processors: 4x Core i3-2310M 2.10GHz
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6470M
Memory: 2.8 Gib
Proprietary amd gpu drivers installed.

```
> sayanstr@sayanstr-HPg6:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 | flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam
https://github.com/flathub/com.valvesoftware.Steam/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions
Overriding TZ to Asia/Kolkata
Running Steam on org.freedesktop.platform 19.08.7 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/sayanstr/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1579321278)
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965 (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965 (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1579321278)
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965 (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965 (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  152
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  152
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  50
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  152
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
crash_20200210224208_1.dmp[144]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20200210224208_1.dmp                                                                                                                                                           
/home/sayanstr/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 722:   139 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"                                               
crash_20200210224208_1.dmp[144]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
crash_20200210224208_1.dmp[144]: error: Couldn't connect to server
crash_20200210224208_1.dmp[144]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20200210224208_1.dmp'', upload no: ''Couldn't connect to server''

> sayanstr@sayanstr-HPg6:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 | flatpak run org.blender.Blender
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Read prefs: /home/sayanstr/.var/app/org.blender.Blender/config/blender/2.81/config/userpref.blend
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965 (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965 (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/dri:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
        error code:   167
        request code: 152
        minor code:   34
        error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed, and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop file in my system contains this code to run flatpak steam :-

> /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64
> --command=/app/bin/steam-wrapper --file-forwarding com.valvesoftware.Steam @@u %U @@

I checked the [flatpak manual](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html) which showed this flag -

```
--env=VAR=VALUE
```

> Set an environment variable in the application. This updates the
> [Environment] group in the metadata. This overrides to the Context
> section from the application metadata. This option can be used
> multiple times.

Since DRI_PRIME=1 can be set as an environment variable for applications to use dedicated GPU like

```
env DRI_PRIME=1 program_to_run
```

I modified the command in my steam desktop file like this -

> /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64
> **--env=DRI_PRIME=1** --command=/app/bin/steam-wrapper --file-forwarding com.valvesoftware.Steam @@u %U @@

Now DRI_PRIME=1 is enabled for steam as a whole which will automatically be used for games at the time of launch. Hope this helps you :-)